# How to apply physics on Collada object node in scenekit

Tags: physics, collision, scenekit

I have a 3d tunnel and a running man in it.I make this tunnel in blender and imported it into scenekit.Now whenever i click on the man it start running and cross out the walls of tunnel.I want the tunnel walls Static so the the moving man should not cross the walls and move only inside the tunnel.I apply physics on tunnel node but it not working it giving message as"warning, Non triangle list element type not yet supported in physics shape generation
"

```
 scene = SCNScene(named: "game.scnassets/UpdatedTunnel/second.dae")!
   let Tunnel = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("SketchUp", recursively: true)!
    TunnelNode.addChildNode(Tunnel)

   scene.rootNode.addChildNode(TunnelNode)

    TunnelNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
```

I am uploading my 3d tunnel image here it looks like cylinder[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPn5t.jpg)Which physics shape i should apply for collision detection.
Can somebody help me how to avoid my moving character not cross out from walls?? Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit is complaining that something in your model prevents it from creating a valid [SCNPhyicsShape](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsShape_Class/).

Try and create a simpler shape (in your 3D tool) for collision detection purposes only and assign this as the SCNPhyicsShape for the simulation.

By default, SceneKit uses the SCNGeometry of the SCNNode (the SCNPhysicsBody belongs to) as the SCNPhyicsShape if you don't assign one.

Regards,
Karl.

Comment: I try to make  geometry as  var shape:SCNPhysicsShape?
        if let geometry = TunnelNode.geometry{
            shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: geometry, options: [SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey: SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron])
            var nodePhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: shape)
            TunnelNode.physicsBody = nodePhysicsBody
            nodePhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
But it still not working.If say i apply physics and collision in blender ,then scenekit accept or not?